# How to get specific value for key from json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, arraylist

I have following code,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var totalPrice = "";
        var jsonList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.price))'
        var jList = JSON.parse(jsonList);

        $("#C_Adults, #C_Children").on('change', function () {
            var adultcount = $("#C_Adults").val();
            var childcount = $("#C_Children").val();
            alert(adultcount);
            alert(childcount);

           //get the needed value here
        });

        alert("js is working");
    });
```

in here the results fo `jsonList` and `jList` shown in the below picture
[image]

what I want is to get `adultprice` and `childprice` seperately, inside the button click

**NOTE: everytime jList count is 1**

hope your help with this.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jList is an array of Objects. Therefore you can get your values like this:

```
var adultprice = jList[0].adultprice;
var childprice = jList[0].childprice;
```

Comment: thanx. I tried this earlier.it was a spelling mistake.anyway thanx. it is working